# dynamically populate dropdown; passing "filename" to SimpleForm() Class

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to dynamically populate a dropdown based upon column names in a csv that the user has uploaded.  After the user uploads the file (variable name is filename) and is redirected to the next page, /analysis/, how do I actually pass the filename to the SimpleForm(form) class to actually generate the dropdown list? 
The code is question is

```
form = SimpleForm(filename)
```

I know that I can't pass filename directly to class SimpleForm(object) but how do I do it?

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()


class SimpleForm(Form):
    list_of_files = ['Standard New/Renew/Upsell/Downsell/Churn Analysis', 'Top Ten Customer Accounts','Churn Analysis']
    # create a list of value/description tuples
    files = [(x, x) for x in list_of_files]
    test = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = None, nrows = 0, header=0)
    second_list = list(test.columns)
    second_files = [(x, x) for x in second_list]
    acheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label', choices=files)
    bcheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label', choices=second_files)
    categories = SelectField('Label',choices = files)



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            file = request.files['file']
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
                if columns_len(filename):
                    title = filename.split('.')[0].title() #creates the title
                    return redirect(url_for('analysis', filename=filename))
                else:
                    flash(u'Your CSV has less than three columns.  Please re-upload', 'error')
            else:
                flash(u'Invalid file type.  Please re-upload', 'error')
        return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/analysis/<filename>', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def analysis(filename):

        form = SimpleForm(filename)
        return render_template('analysis.html', filename=filename, form=form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the `__init__` method to accept your parameter and set `choices` there.

```
class SimpleForm(Form):
    acheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label')
    bcheckbox = MultiCheckboxField('Label')
    categories = SelectField('Label')

    def __init__(self, filename, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        list_of_files = ['Standard New/Renew/Upsell/Downsell/Churn Analysis', 'Top Ten Customer Accounts','Churn Analysis']
        # create a list of value/description tuples
        files = [(x, x) for x in list_of_files]
        test = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = None, nrows = 0, header=0)
        second_list = list(test.columns)
        second_files = [(x, x) for x in second_list]

        self.acheckbox.choices = files
        self.bcheckbox.choices = second_files
        self.categories.choices = files
```

Comment: worked like a charm....I need to do some more reading on classes and parameters...  I'll definitely start looking more into that....thanks a million